# generation of project file for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

When running:

swift package generate-xcodeproj

The fallowing defaults are set that create manual work every time we make changes the the Package.swift file.

1. The Base SDK is set to macOS instead of iOS
   [BaseSDKIssue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiGzJ.png)
2. The Deployment targets are set to default values (iOS8 instead of iOS13 is the exact change)
   [DeploymentTargetsIssue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVyET.png)

the modules where created with:

swift package init --name xyz --type library

//modify Package.swift to have dependencies xyz has

swift package generate-xcodeproj

How can I get the Base SDK set to iOS and the Deployment targets set to iOS13 when i run generate-xcodeproj

This is a simple structure of what I am trying to do [SimpleStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5x1W.png)

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Added exact expected outcome at the bottom of the post

Comment: Is there a reason you need the xcode project to have those settings? A swift package should be pretty much independent of the generated xcode project. If there is an iOS component to it, it should probably be a separate project that has the swift package as a dependency.

Comment: The swift package is using iOS components defined in the iOS sdk such as:

NSPersistentContainer

and that has a min version of 10, there will be other components that use elements from the the iOS SDK

I also plan on having some modules extend the cocoatouch sdk for UI modules, these will defiantly need these settings.

Comment: OK so after reading your comment again I see the confusion. I am generating an xcode project to make modifications to module, and write unit tests. I then use the test target to run my tests. There is also an outer most project which pulls all the swift modules in, this is where i would like 

swift package generate-xcodeproj

to set iOS and iOS13 as defaults instead of MacOS and iOS8 as i do not want to go in and update every module that is listed as a dependency every time make a change in a module and pull that into my main application file

Comment: I updated the question with a sample of how I am trying to modularize components. It is also a possibility I am using SPM in a way it was not designed to? However I was expecting this to work with SPM being included in XCode11

Comment: I think I see what you mean. Answer below

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/creating_a_swift_package_with_xcode) about setting up packages. In the swift package file you can define platforms, as seen here:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.1
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyLibrary",
    platforms: [
        .macOS(.v10_13),
    ],
    products: [
        .library(name: "MyLibrary", targets: ["MyLibrary"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://url/of/another/package/named/Utility", from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "MyLibrary", dependencies: ["Utility"]),
        .testTarget(name: "MyLibraryTests", dependencies: ["MyLibrary"]),
    ]
)
```

I'm not sure there is anything beyond that to set up the Xcode project, as swift packages in general are set up to be pretty platform agnostic.

Comment: Awesome i did not know about the platforms list object.
I will look into the option for that but it looks very promising
Thank you!